# Why same namespace errors for Linq methods?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, visual-studio-2013

I have refactored my project, which is small, to correct namespaces and class names. Somewhere along the way, something has gone screwy and I get a compile errors relating to Linq methods until I fix it with a random namespace in the ObservableCollection class file. The linq errors are only related to the ObservableCollection and not any other objects in the winform.

*This feels like a Visual Studio bug as I feel I have checked everything.*

I have a winform, a class(MyObject) and another class(ObservableCollection) in the same project.

They all have a reference to System.Linq and all have a namespace of `MyProject.ProjectCategory`

**The winform looks like this**

```
using System.Linq;
namespace MyProject.ProjectCategory
private ObservableCollection<MyObject> myList;

// ...later in a method
myList.All(f => f.Title != "Test")

// the list of errors contains any Linq methods and is a long list. Here is one example
// ERROR: MyProject.ProjectCategory.ObservableCollection<MyObject> does not contain 
// a definition for 'All' and no extension method 'All' accepting the first argument  
// of type MyProject.ProjectCategory.ObservableCollection<MyObject>
```

Here are the results of if I change the namespace for the class(ObservableCollection)

```
MyProject.ProjectCategory (as above) ERROR
MyProject ERROR
Fubar COMPILES
MyProject.ProjectCategory.Fubar COMPILES
```

I have tried Cleaning, rebuilding, deleting all bin and obj folders. Checked all .Net version numbers are the same. Checked reference paths.

I can live with and Fubar namespace but would go with a fix if anyone has a clue.

Comment: Do you have an extension method in `MyProject` called `All`? One that may not be getting renamed when you change the namespace?

Comment: @RonBeyer Did a search, No. But there is another class file in a referenced project containing my custom linq extensions, but that namespace remains as System.Linq and there are no extensions for `All` in that one. To be clearer, `All` is just one example, I am getting the erro for many different linq expressions, Find, Where etc

Comment: There are sometimes compiler errors, but "I feel like I've checked everything and I can't figure it out" is not evidence of a compiler bug. It's evidence that your feeling is wrong.  **Produce a small, complete program that reproduces the problem**. In doing so you will 99% likely find the problem yourself. If you don't, then post it here and someone will tell you what you've done wrong.

Comment: Dose your ObservableCollection implement IEnumerable?

Comment: @FilipCordas Simply changing the namespace corrects the issue. Why does any other code change matter at this point?

Comment: Read my answer; changing the namespace changes the type the unqualified name `ObservableCollection` inside your winform resolves to. Your implementation of `ObservableCollection<T>` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` and the compiler can't resolve the call to any valid extension methods. When you change the namespace, that same unqualified name resolves to some other type that does implement `IEnumerable<T>` and the extensions methods are resolved correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `ObservableCollection<T>` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`. Linq extension methods can only be applied to objects that implement the interface:

```
 public static bool All<T>(this IEnumerable<T>, .... )
 public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T>, .... )
 public static T First<T>(this IEnumerable<T>, ...)
 etc.
```

You also have to understand how namespaces work. Consider the following horrible namespace example simply to illustrate your issue:

```
//using System; intentionally commented out

namespace System.Foo
{
     class Foo
     {
         String s; //huh? Why is System.String addressable with 
                   //unqualified name?
}
```

What happens here is that when you are *inside* a namespace `A.B` block, it automatically allows you to refer to all types defined in the namespace `A.B` *and* `A` without fully qualifying their names.

Translated to your specific scenario, this means that when your `ObservableCollection<T>` is defined in the namespace `MyProject.ProjectCategory` or `MyProject`, the name `ObservableCollection` inside your `winform` refers to *that type* and the extension method calls can not be resolved.

However, when you change the namespace of your `ObservableCollection<T>` to `Fubar` or `MyProject.ProjectCategory.Fubar` then the name `ObservableCollection<T>` inside `winform` stops referring to your implementation and the compiler is resolving it to some other type (probably `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>`) that *does* implement `IEnumerable<T>` and all linq extension methods suddenly start working.

Comment: This works! `public class ObservableCollection<T> : System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged` thank you for the clue and explanation in your answer

Comment: @Valamas-AUS you seem to have a basic misunderstanding of what is happening here. You should look into a beginners course in c# first and what are namespaces are if you want to learn.